# Paperclip content_type validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

Is there a way to validate files based on content and not on extension in paperclip.
If I rename a `.dll` file to `.png` and upload it. It passes the `content_type` validation but fails saying `xxx.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command`. Is there any way to get around this?